# Sql Querying with Ajax while offline returning blank

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'll over simplify the problem in order to make it easier. I'm using the following Ajax script to call another .php file and have it return the results to the original page. I'm using Apache offline and the page is unfortunately returning blank.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showInfo(str) {
        var xmlhttp;

          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          } 
          else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status== 200) {
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","practice.php?q="+str,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
}

window.onload = function() { showInfo('bleh'); };

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

//Then the code below is another file called practice.php, which corresponds the ajax above

```
<? 
    $test = $_GET['q'];
    echo $test;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure $_GET is a case-sensitive variable name on most OSes, so $_Get would be empty.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately that wasn't a problem with my code, I simply made the mistake when bringing it over to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

I would comment if I could -

What happens when you try to hit the page directly (ie put practice.php?q=test) in the browser?

Also I can't find any documentation (it's hard to google it), but it wouldn't hurt to make the opening tag `<?php` instead of just `<?`